# Getting and Setting the left Property of WPF Canvas control

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I know this question has been asked a dozen times , but I couldn't find an answer to solve my problem. Basically, I have an instance of `Canvas` control class which contains an `Image` control. I want to move the `Canvas` horizontally on X-axis until it disappears. Here is my code:

```
void moveCanvas()
{               
    int pos = Convert.ToInt32(image.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)); //this line throws an exception 

    if (pos >= 800)
    {
        Canvas.SetLeft(image, 20);
    }
    else
    {
        Canvas.SetLeft(image, step); 
    }
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    step += 20;
    moveCanvas(); 
}
```

I'm really new to WPF and I have no idea other than this how to solve this problem.

Comment: I'd check what is returned by `image.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)`. Maybe it's an error with the conversion. What is the exact exception thrown? Never forget to include that when asking a question. Also this piece of code is trying to modify the `Canvas.Left` attached property of the image in your `Canvas` while you said you want to move the whole `Canvas` horizontally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value of the `Canvas.Left` property is `double.NaN`, which can't be converted to `int`.

You should initialize `Canvas.Left` before starting your animation:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(image, 0);
...

void moveCanvas()
{               
    var pos = Canvas.GetLeft(image); 

    if (pos >= 800)
    {
        Canvas.SetLeft(image, 20);
    }
    else
    {
        Canvas.SetLeft(image, step); 
    }
}
```

---

It might also be a lot simpler to use a WPF animation for moving the Image:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(image, 0);

image.BeginAnimation(
    Canvas.LeftProperty,
    new DoubleAnimation(800, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```